# Jquery "the event object" trying to change "CSS" of <div> tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>chapter 5</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div >
        <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
$(function() {
    $("div").on("hover", function(event) {
        if(event.type === "mouseenter") {
            $(this).css("background", "blue");
        } 
        else {
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

so according to my Jquery: when I bring mouse over to  tags it should change its colour to red and when any other even inside  tag except mouse enter it should change to blue. But nothing is happening?

I have tried other functions with event which works fairly well I can not understand why this one is not working do I have to do something with "css" maybe?

Comment: I'm wondering why you did not use `mouseenter` from the beginning. Keep in mind to not add overhead such as that in your code

Comment: I was actually trying out some examples from a book to learn jQuery interestingly the book is published in 2013 and still using "hover" which is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name `"hover"` used as a shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the `"hover"` pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

Listen to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of the `hover`:

```
$("div").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event) {
   $(this).css("background", event.type === "mouseenter" ? "blue" : "red");
});
```

Alternatively you can pass an object to the `.on()` method:

```
$("div").on({
   mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).css("background", "blue");
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("background", "red");
   }
});
```